# Dynamic view id using pretty faces navigation refuses to work

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I am attempting to migrate an application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1.  The code below worked in the 1.2.
I am using PrettyFaces 3.3.3, MyFaces 2.1.

in pretty-config.xml:

```
<url-mapping id="seSite">
  <pattern value="/sites/#{seViewChooserBean.urlSiteType}/#{seViewChooserBean.siteId}"/>
  <view-id value="#{seViewChooserBean.getSiteViewId}"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="seSiteProps">
  <pattern value="/sites/#{sePropsBean.urlSiteType}/#{sePropsBean.siteId}/properties"/>
  <view-id value="/pages/se/site/props.xhtml"/>
  <action>#{sePropsBean.init}</action>
</url-mapping>
```

I have a request with URL: http://example.com/myapp/sites/object/309847
This request successfully matches the url mapping id "seSite" and getSiteViewId is invoked on seViewChooserBean and returns the result "pretty:seSiteProps". I have debugged and confirmed this. For your reference this is the bean code for ViewChooserBean.java:

```
public String getSiteViewId() {

    if (siteType == SiteType.TYPE) {
        // redirect to tag list view
        initSiteBean("seTagListBean", TagListBean.class);
        return "pretty:seTagList";
    }
    else {
        // redirect to site properties view
        initSiteBean("sePropsBean", PropertiesBean.class);
        return "pretty:seSiteProps";
    }
}
```

After that prettyfaces then attempts to forward to the new view id seSiteProps but the new generated URL is not processed by pretty faces because (from the logs): "Request is not mapped using PrettyFaces. Continue."

So I get 404 response for URL http:://example.com/myapp/sites/object/309847/properties.

Note that this url  match to view id seSiteProps.

I have debugged this up into the pretty faces filter and discovered the following:

After the initial request for http://example.com/myapp/sites/object/309847, the DynaviewEngine.processDynaView is invoked and generates the correct target url http:://example.com/sites/object/309847/properties and forwards via faces request.

Then, with a breakpoint in PrettyFilter.doFilter() I observed the following:
In PrettyFilter.doFilter() method: isUrlMappingForward(req) returns false, therefore request is not processed by prettyfaces.  Why??

```
// isUrlMappingForward returns false.  The request has url http:://example.com/myapp/sites/object/309847/properties on it.
if (!isUrlMappingForward(req))
{
  mapping = getConfig().getMappingForUrl(url);
}
```

Also, note that if I put the request http:://example.com/myapp/sites/object/309847/properties directly in the browser the page IS processed by prettyfaces and isUrlMappingForward(req) returns true and it loads correctly in the browser.

I was thinking I've missed something obvious here as the problem hasn't been reported elsewhere as far as I can tell.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.
Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm very surprised that returning PrettyFaces navigation strings from dynaview methods ever worked. This isn't documented anywhere and I doubt that this has been tested in detail. So basically you are using the dynaview feature in an very weird way.

So I recommend to return plain JSF view IDs instead which should work fine. See the documentation for details:

http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.dynaview

Comment: Ok thanks.  Really interesting that it worked in JSF 1.2 version.  In my debugging it looked like there was only one line of code stopping this functionality from working ie the urlMappingForward check.  It was introduced to fix another bug (fix #150 or something like that). Would be a good feature to have in my opinion.