# pretty faces dynamic-view-id and el paramteres

Tags: jsf, primefaces, prettyfaces

I trying to resolve a issue regarding pretty faces pass parameters to bean:

I have configured pretty-config mapping as follows:

```
<url-mapping id="frontend_search"> 
    <pattern value="/szukaj/#{ categoryId }" />   <!-- pass parameter from url -->
    <view-id value="#{searchView.getViewPath}" />  <!-- dynamic view id -->
</url-mapping>
```

Problem is that. The parameter is not being passed into request parametersMap

```
    String catId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("categoryId");
```

is null

but when i change configuration of pretty faces to the following (no dynamic view-id)

```
<url-mapping id="frontend_search"> 
    <pattern value="/szukaj/#{ categoryId }" />   <!-- pass parameter from url -->
    <view-id value="/faces/template_1/frontend/pages/products/search.xhtml" />  <!-- no dynamic view id -->
</url-mapping>
```

it works fine!. I cant understand why that happen. Meaby somebody have been that problem and can help here? I Will grateful for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic view id using pretty faces navigation refuses to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290077/dynamic-view-id-using-pretty-faces-navigation-refuses-to-work)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this way isn't working. But you could bind the parameter directly to the `searchView`, which could work much better:

```
<url-mapping id="frontend_search"> 
    <pattern value="/szukaj/#{searchView.categoryId}" />
    <view-id value="#{searchView.getViewPath}" />
</url-mapping>
```

You will just need to add the `categoryId` property to your bean.